# Why doesn't this trigger work properly?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers, oracle-sqldeveloper

From what I have read about triggers and how they work, I thought that this trigger would insert data into the relations related to my table phonenumber after I insert values into it. I'm using dbms_random to create a random 5 digit usageID not already in the usage table (or atleast that's what I had thought it would do).

```
create or replace TRIGGER addPhoneLine
AFTER INSERT ON phoneNumber
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
  FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
    primNum varchar(12);
    acctNum numeric(5);
    NEWusageID_new varchar(5);

BEGIN

    if :new.primaryNumber is not NULL then
        select acctID, primaryNumber into acctNum, primNum
        from account A
        where A.primaryNumber = :new.primaryNumber;

        select to_char(round(dbms_random.value(10000, 99999),0)) into 
NEWusageID_new from dual
        minus
        select usageID from usage;

        INSERT INTO acct_num VALUES
        (acctNum, primNum, :new.phonenumber);

        INSERT INTO phone_usage VALUES
        (NEWusageID_new, :new.phonenumber);
    end if;

END;
```

But it throws the following errors when I attempt to insert into the phoneNumber table:

> ORA-01403: no data found
>
> ORA-06512: at "ADDPHONELINE", line 9
>
> ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'ADDPHONELINE'

The relevant tables were created as follows:

```
create table phoneNumber(phoneNumber varchar(12) PRIMARY KEY, primaryNumber varchar(12));

create table acct_num(acctID numeric(5) references ACCOUNT, primaryNumber varchar(12) references ACCOUNT,  phoneNumber varchar(12) references phoneNumber);

create table phone_usage(usageID varchar(5) references USAGE, phoneNumber varchar(12) references PHONENUMBER)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your trigger is based on an insert on table `phoneNumber` and the error "No Data Found" is thrown when a SELECT INTO is used and it doesnt find any information to insert.

So the problem must be this statement.

```
select acctID, primaryNumber into acctNum, primNum
from account A
where A.primaryNumber = :new.primaryNumber;
```

Are you certain that the `:new.primaryNumber` exists in the `account` table when this trigger is active?

Maybe you are only populating the `account` table after this insert is complete?

Answer (score 0):

The below query is returning no rows, as per error description you posted.  Either your :new.primaryNumber is incorrect or there is no matching record in the account table.

```
Begin 
   select acctID, primaryNumber into acctNum, primNum
    from account A
    where A.primaryNumber = :new.primaryNumber;
exception when others then
  insert your favorite logging method here logging out your :new.primaryNumber
end;
```

Comment: How can I check for the value of :new.primaryNumber? Because I tried that query with :new.primaryNumber substituted with what I had inserted as my primary number and the query returned the acctID and primaryNumber

Comment: @JR3652 I have updated my answer with exception handling.  The way that you log depends on what tool you are using to run this.  Worst case create a log table and insert a message with :new.primaryNumber.

Answer (score 0):

I show you here what will happen when dbms_random gives a value (NEWusageID_new), which exists in the usage:

```
DECLARE
   i   NUMBER;
BEGIN
   SELECT 15 INTO i FROM DUAL
   MINUS
   SELECT 15 FROM DUAL;
END;

ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: in line 4
```

Use a sequence instead.